# HP ALM - TD Connect

Tags: alm

We have a VBA macro based automation tool which gets connected to HP ALM. In order to connect to ALM, we run the TDConnect.exe file which is downloaded through ALM.

Currently, we are unable to install the TDConnect file in windows 7 machine (Installation is successful in windows XP machine).

Could you kindly provide your valuable suggestions on this ?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Any error messages or details would be helpful. I would also try to disable UAC and run installer with elevated privileges (run as administrator)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 and above, somethimes are tricky with the admin permissions, how are you installing the tdconnect? and by installing I suppose you are registering it aswell, if not then using OTA will not work as expected.

Normally, I would suggest to log in with an user account that has all admin permissions (Run as, create registry key, create files in programs data, etc) and install/register the components using the URL of your ALM + /qcbin/start_a.jsp?common=true .

For example:

http://myalm.mydomain:8080/qcbin/start_a.jsp?common=true

Also make sure UAC is disabled and the webpage is added to the trusted sites when doing this for the first time.